Why does an exception occur when binding to a socket server?
IPAddress IpAddress_ = IPAddress.Parse(ip_address);
int PortNumber = port_number;

// 소켓 서버로 실행
if (Socket_select == false)
{
    m_Socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp);
    m_IpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IpAddress_, port_number);

    m_AcceptCallback = new AsyncCallback(accept_Callback);        
    m_ReceiveCallback = new AsyncCallback(DataReceive_Callback);   
    m_CloseCallback = new AsyncCallback(Close_Callback);         

    try
    {
                    
        m_Socket.Bind(m_IpEndPoint); // 1
        m_Socket.Listen(5);         // 2
        m_Socket.BeginAccept(m_AcceptCallback, m_Socket); // 3
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        m_String_DataLog = ex.ToString();
    }
}

m_Socket.Bind() throws a System.Net.Sockets.SocketException.
It does not occur if I set IPAddress.Any, but it occurs if I set an IP other than that.

What does the exception say? Does the computer have the specified IP address?

The IP address that you bind needs to be a local address used by one of the network adapters. Why are you using a raw socket anyway, why not use TcpClient?
